# BitBucket Pipeline cannot find container after ssh into DigitalOcean Droplet

Tags: docker, bitbucket, digital-ocean, bitbucket-pipelines

Here is my code

```
- step:
    name: SSH to Digital Ocean and update docker image
    script:
      - head ~/.ssh/config
      - ssh -i ~/.ssh/config root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
      - docker ps
      - docker rm -f gvcontainer
      - docker image rm -f myrepo/myimage:tag
      - docker pull myrepo/myimage:tag
      - docker run --name gvcontainer -p 12345:80 -d=true --restart=always myrepo/myimage:tag
    services:
      - docker
```

Here I can see that the Pipeline ssh into my DO droplet successfully, but for some reason (I guess, it was too quick to type the "docker ps"; it should to wait a few seconds, but I just don't know how to postpone the operation) it could not find the container.

So I manually ssh into my droplet and checked, the gvcontainer is there.

[image]

Why might be the reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands listed after your SSH session are not being run on the remote system - they're being run in Pipelines. Since the Pipelines container doesn't have a `gvcontainer` to remove, it returns that error.

You have several options, one of which I outlined in answering your other question (pass the commands as arguments to SSH, as in `ssh -i /path/to/key user@host "command1 && command2"`). Another option would be to put a script on the droplet that does all the things you want, and have Pipelines execute it via SSH (`ssh -i /path/to/key user@host "./do-all-the-things.sh"`).

Comment: thanks Jim, I think you are correct. Although I have used up all my free building time on Bitbucket, I will have to confirm it next month.

Comment: hi Jim, as my BitBucket free pipeline time has been used up. I wrote a .bat file which has the: ssh -i /path/to/key user@host "command1 && command2". But still, it throws error: No such container: gvcontainer.  please help